# I can't increase the volume via Autohotkey script

Tags: autohotkey

I can't increase the volume via Autohotkey script.
The shortcut for increasing volume in VLC is <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>UP ARROW</kbd>.
This script doesn't work.

SetTitleMatchMode, 2

ControlSend, ,  {CTRLDOWN}{UP}{CTRLUP}, VLC media player

Return

Comment: You should still consider using the more reliable `ahk_class QWidget` as the window identifier, as described in ElliotDeNolf's solution. E.g. if you have a [google search for VLC media player](https://www.google.de/search?q=VLC%20media%20player) open, the script may accidentally send the keys to your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#Up::ControlSend,, ^{Up}, ahk_class QWidget
#Down::ControlSend,, ^{Down}, ahk_class QWidget
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot. I extracted keystrokes ^{Up} and edited my script . It works.   `SetTitleMatchMode, 2
ControlSend, , ^{Up}, VLC media player
Return`